# Resetting Timer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, disabled-control

So My game is almost done with its alpha devlopment then im going to launch it.

Just on issue though. I created button using div element. This button(div) is only supposed to to be clicked once and then be disabled.

Is it possible to disable this button(div) element that i made?

Here is my code

```js
function speedOne(){
 if (incomeDisplay >= boosterCostOne){
  
  document.getElementById("incomeDisplay").innerHTML = "Arrings : &alefsym; " + (incomeDisplay = incomeDisplay - boosterCostOne);
    
  document.getElementById("speedOne").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  
 booster = 2;
  
 }
}
```

```css
.speed-boosters {
 background-color: royalblue;
 width:170px;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 padding:15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 
  1px 2px 5px black,
  -1px 2px 5px black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.speed-boosters:hover{
 background-color: deepskyblue;
  box-shadow: 
  1px 2px 10px black,
  -1px 2px 10px black;
}

.speed-boosters:active{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 2px black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "speed-boosters" id="speedOne" onclick="speedOne()">Speed Booster - 1</div>
     <p>Buy Speed Booster - 1 : Boost Income speeds by 10%</p>
```

so as you can see my buttons is pretty but it is clickable many times

how can make a play able to only click it once?

Comment: you can see that i have tried disabling it via the attribute setting but i forgot that divs dont really have this function how can i do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable a `div`. You have to switch it to a `button` (that's what it is).

Then you can use:

```
document.getElementById("speedOne").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

You can also style your button based on the `disabled` attribute:

```
.speed-boosters:disabled {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```js
function speedOne(){
  console.log('foo');
  document.getElementById("speedOne").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

```css
.speed-boosters {
 background-color: royalblue;
 width:170px;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 padding:15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 
  1px 2px 5px black,
  -1px 2px 5px black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.speed-boosters:hover{
 background-color: deepskyblue;
  box-shadow: 
  1px 2px 10px black,
  -1px 2px 10px black;
}

.speed-boosters:active{
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 2px black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.speed-boosters:disabled {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class = "speed-boosters" id="speedOne" onclick="speedOne()">Speed Booster - 1</button>
<p>Buy Speed Booster - 1 : Boost Income speeds by 10%</p>
```

Comment: looks like im going to have make due with the button then thanks bud i just thought it will be possible